# Weird iPhone 4 simulator behavior - UITextViews stacked on top of each other

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview, simulator

I just finished up my **storyboard based iPhone app** (I'm developing on an **iPhone 5**). Just before submitting it to the Appstore, I thought of making sure everything looks fine on an iPhone 4. So I launch my app in the **simulator** with **iPhone 4**.

**And what I see baffles me**. Basically *every single view object*, particularly textview, are **stacked on top of each other**. Basically everything scrollable's **messed up**. In some textviews even, the *initial scroll position* has been set to say 100px, which means that the textview's showing the middle of the content in a textview and there'sno way to scroll to top.

Every time I make an ajustments to the storyboard view to fit the iPhone 4, **the view on iPhone 5 instead looks weird**. Most of the time, the stacked objects on iPhone 4 simulator *can't even be unstacked*.

**Am I the only one experiencing this**? I cant find any post about it. Could it be that there's something messed up with my simulator? **Any setting I've missed**? The only solution I can think of now is to have a **seperate SB for iP4 and iP5**, but I really would rather not go through the pain of doing that. Any comment or idea is greatly appreciated.

### How it looks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that your autosizing struts and springs are set appropriately.

[image: Autosizing area of Size Inspector]

The views need to either dock to the top, or bottom and the views that you want to stretch should have the flexible vertical set.

Comment: Are you sure it is set correctly for each view? Is it set for all the views that are incorrectly placed? Any controls created in code will also need Autoresizing behavior set correctly. This should be all you need if you only require minor stretching and repositioning for iPhone 5 and 4 compatibility. You should not do a separate xib unless the views are vastly different, which usually should not be the case.

Comment: To set in code: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW5

Comment: sorry am i supposed to use Show: frame rectangle, or Show: Layout Rectangle? Or what is it you mean I should change in the size inspector? I might have misunderstood you. What're saying sounds resonable

Comment: The Autosizing area. You can make width or height flexible, and then also pin top, left, right or bottom to parent view. In the example area, it will show how that view stretches and shrinks with the parent view.

Comment: Oh okay I don't have that in my size inspector. I uploaded a pic and put it in my question for you to see. How can I view that Autosizing?

Comment: I found it now, I had to deselect "Auto resizing". Trying it as we speak. Bare with me

Comment: It looks like you have Auto Layout turned on. That is a whole different animal than simple Autoresizing. Auto Layout requires iOS 6+ as well.

Comment: Ok got it. Am I supposed to change the Arrange: , change the error-bar looking objects inside the autosizing frame? I've never used this before

Comment: Click the red arrows and lines. Maybe this will help. http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling . Don't forget to upvote if you found an answer helpful.

Comment: absolutely I will, just got to get this sorted. Really don't know what arrows to click but hopefully your link will tell me